# Remove duplicate rows from pandas dataframe with user defined equality condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Is there a way in pandas to select unique rows from a pandas dataframe where the condition of equality between rows is slightly complicated and has to be written in a separate function say `equals(row1, row2)`.

Comment: I think you need create mask - boolean Series and then use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Comment: So need return mask from your custom function `mask = equals(row1, row2)` and then `df[mask]`

Comment: maybe you could use `DataFrame.drop` and update it with your condition. depends how complicated the condition is

Comment: @Roxanne by complicated I mean it is not straight forward string or integer comparison, say some permutations of string are equal and some are not.

Comment: In general this would require quadratic number of calls of the comparison function. Could the equality maybe be written as `key(row1) == key(row2)`, where `key()` returns some simple value?